# Why does it take so long for Ubuntu to say "command not found"

Tags: command-line, bash

For some reason, with my setup, it can take Ubuntu several seconds to respond with "command not found" when I accidentally typo a command.  Why does it take so long?  Is there any way to shorten the period of time I have to wait?

I do have 13 directories in my PATH, but even so (most of them have just a few files in them), it shouldn't take several seconds to search 13 directories for a command right?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The shell does more than just looking in `$PATH`. If a command is not found, the bash function `command_not_found_handle` is executed which in its turn call the python script `/usr/lib/command-not-found`. This searches in the packages list for programs that should be installed for the command to work. In the case of a typo which you know how to solve, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to abort the search process.

Example of a useful message for a typo:

```
$ aptget update
No command 'aptget' found, did you mean:
 Command 'apt-get' from package 'apt' (main)
aptget: command not found
```

Example of a useful message for a missing package:

```
$ deja-dup
The program 'deja-dup' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

See also the rationale behind this, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommandNotFoundMagic

Comment: Linus posted something on this: https://plus.google.com/u/0/102150693225130002912/posts/iz7zR9B1Prv

Comment: And I consider this to be a truly amazing feature!  If you use a command you expect to be present but isn't there, you are directly told what to type to install it.

Answer (score 8):

It's because of a package named "command-not-found". You can uninstall it to shorten the response time.