# How to catch the command failure events in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to execute the `script` whenever the command fails.
We all know that if the command is failed `$?` value will not be equal to `0`.It gives the value `127` if command fails.

The script is ready but I am unable to catch the command fail events.

For example, if I try a command which is not present then it has to take that input and pass it to the script. I have figured all the logic except catching the failed events. How can I do this?
`Example`

```
$-> code
```

code is not the command here so it fails in execution automatically run the following command with taking `code` as input to the `cd` command.

```
cd code
```

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? Do you want this to happen for *all* commands or only those you chose? Are you just looking for `command || echo "failed"`?

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the quick response . I have added the details with small requirement example please check this

Comment: You can also use `exit $?` in a script to test for errors a command returns.

Comment: @JohnAnkanna OK, but is this something that should happen for *all* failed commands or only for the ones you choose?

Comment: @Rinzwind you got the good point .But I am trying to make the things to take the failed command as input to another command which has to run automatically with out .So I asked for failed events

Comment: @terdon for all the commands .  IF we get one slice we can bake another slice easily i think so

Comment: Well, no. Making it work for all commands and all types of failure (command not found is not at all the same as command failed) is far, far more complicated than simply making it work for the commands you chose. You could write a function (`execute` or whatever) and have that deal with the errors, so when you want to treat a command this way, you'd run `execute command`, for example. Frankly, I can't imagine why you would want to catch *all* failed commands.

Comment: @terdon you got the good point ,but where can i keep the execute function is it in `.bashrc` file or some other and one more will that run every time i enter the wrong command? Thanks for taking time and responding

Comment: Yes, it would be in `~/.bashrc` or, better, `~/.profile` but you would have to explicitly call it and pass it the command you want to run. It wouldn't work for all commands. If that is acceptable, let me know and I can post an answer giving you the details.

Comment: @terdon explicit calling ? if that means we can use the `||` operator but can we make it automatically take initiation

Comment: No, I mean that running `foo` won't run your script if it fails. Running `myFunction foo` will catch it. So it won't work for all commands, only for those you run through `myFunction`. Please [edit] and give more detail. Explain clearly if you want this for *all* commands and explain what you mean by a "command". Should this only happen for things you run manually or for all failed commands on the system? Ideally, explain the problem you are trying to solve. This looks a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42277/discussion-between-john-ankanna-and-terdon).

Comment: It sounds like you want to intercept the bash shell's `command_not_found` handler: see [Is there a way to capture a user command to bash which was not found and do something with it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9895646/4440445) and [How do I teach bash in Ubuntu some curse words?](http://askubuntu.com/a/73282/178692)

Comment: Not all commands use  exit status to signify failure. Good example is `file` command. If  you do something like `file ASDF` it will print `SDF: cannot open `ASDF' (No such file or directory)` and return exit status of 0. It really depends on your concrete example. So, no - there is no silver bullet

Answer (score 1):

What could be done is to use functions. They run as subshells, so you can catch errors of one subshell via redirection, and send it to other function to deal with it. The script bellow handles only failure of one command.

```
#!/bin/bash
err_handling()
{
    # grab command from output
    cmd=$(awk -F ':' '{print $1}'  < /dev/stdin)
    # re-run with some proper argument
    $cmd /dev/sda1

}

main()
{
    # let main stop on error
    # so note , last line won't run !!!
    set -e
    # This will fail with df: asdf: No such file or directory
    # err_handling function will grab the command name 
    # and rerun it
    df asdf
    echo "Last line"
}

# Run main with redirecting stderr to stdout
# and original stdout to /dev/null. That way
# only stderr goes via pipe
main  2>&1 >/dev/null | err_handling
```

You could handle multiple commands, if you tell `awk` to filter output. For instance, this reads all stderr form main, and for each err line, extracts command. `case...esac` is used to handle specific cases of errors

```
#!/bin/bash
err_handling()
{
    while read line
    do
        # grab command from output
        cmd=$(awk -F ':' '{print $1}'  <<< "$line" )
        # re-run with some proper argument
        case $line in
            # do something with cmd depending on error
            *not\ found*) echo "$cmd wasn't found" ;;
            *No\ such\ file*) echo "$cmd didn't find your file" ;;
        esac

    done

}

main()
{
    # let main stop on error
    # so note , last line won't run if set -x is set !!!
    # set -x 
    # This will fail with df: asdf: No such file or directory
    # err_handling function will grab the command name 
    # and rerun it
    df asdf
    asdf
}

# Run main with redirecting stderr to stdout
# and original stdout to /dev/null. That way
# only stderr goes via pipe
main  2>&1 >/dev/null | err_handling
```

Note, as i mention in the comments - some commands don't use stderr, for instance `file` command. In such case, you'd need to redirect its stdin and handle it via pipe or otherwise