# Execute a script each time a non-defined alias/function is used in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, zsh

Suppose I have a function that is not defined neither as an alias or a function.

How can I set zsh to execute a script each time the alias is not recognized ( e.g edit my ~/.zshrc to add this precise function?

Comment: You're probably looking for the function `command_not_found_handle`. At least, that's what it is in Bash. It should be defined already, so check its definition with `type command_not_found_handle`. Let me know if this works and I'll write you a full answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I teach bash in Ubuntu some curse words?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73262/how-do-i-teach-bash-in-ubuntu-some-curse-words)